# AutoMayhem - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, music, video-games, science

[image: AutoMayhem]

Clues:

[text within symbol] 79(I)

[musical notation with 3 circled areas]

[three blank lines, the third has a # symbol]

325:327=1, 329:331=1, 336:338=1, 341=1, 345=1, 892=1, 894=1, 896=1, 898=1, 900:901=1, 903=1, 905=1, 909=1, 911=1, 1459=1, 1461=1, 1463=1, 1465=1, 1470:1472=1, 1477=1, 2026=1, 2028=1, 2030=1, 2032=1, 2034:2035=1, 2037=1, 2039=1, 2043=1, 2045=1, 2593:2595=1, 2597:2599=1, 2604=1, 2607=1, 2609=1, 2613=1

Instructions: Find the make and model of the vehicle

Comment: It might help if you put these as spoiler text in your actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The N64 cartridge:

> Atomic number of gold = 79, therefore the game in question is GoldenEye

which links up with the comment about Arecibo because

> the climax of the film was shot at the Arecibo observatory

This leads us to believe that the car

> features prominently in the GoldenEye film, like the BMW Z3, Aston Martin DB5 or Ferrari F355

However, when you

> draw a pixel-based diagram similar to the Arecibo message, using the numerical clues, you get something else: at first I attempted to use the max number of 2631 to generate a rectangle, either 13 by 201 or 39 by 67, however those did not make sense. Later I saw that the 'ones' are in 5 groups, so by trial and error trying to make the groups line up, I managed to get the following by using a rectangle length of 567: (only a piece is shown) [image: Arecibo clue]

which when typed in text is

> 00 = RX

now since the game refers to

> James Bond, who is 007

that substitution leads to

> 007, but 00 = RX => RX7, which the gives the make and model of the car as Mazda RX7

However

> this does not make use of the music notation clue, something perhaps to do with staff/bar/measure/sharp, however I believe that that clue was intended to point to Arecibo, which was short-circuited by the OP's comment

> [OP Edit] The music notation shown is a percussion clef, meant to convey that the rhythm is what is important. The first two measures of the 007 Goldeneye game starts with two heavy high notes, followed by a long low note, repeated, then 5 short high notes. These were meant to be the clues to develop the Arecibo rectangle - dit dit dah, dit dit dah, dit dit dit dit dit = UU5. By creating a spreadsheet with columns to UU, and 5 rows, the Arecibo message can be found!

> [OP Edit] Also, if you google "UU5", you'll find the top result to be an old Mazda rectifier.